# PHP in_array & storing values in new array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi basically I am storing form field names in an array. This is working fine as I am able to print out the array and see it's contents. The problem I am having is checking those contents and based on them storing new values in a new array.

PHP

```
$required = array('frm_companyName', 'frm_hrManager', 'frm_lnManager');
$fieldArray = array();
$errorArray = array();
```

...

```
foreach ($required as $field)  {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $fieldArray[] = $field;
    }
}
```

...

```
if (in_array("frm_companyName", $fieldArray)) {
    $errorArray[] = "Company Name";
}
```

When I print out the $errorArray[] I am returning an empty array (but $fieldArray[] does show the contents. Any Ideas? I know it's bound to be something simple. /Thanks

UPDATE:

I have changed the line

```
if ( in_array("frm_companyName", $fieldArray)) {
    $errorArray[] = "Company Name";
}
```

to

```
if ( in_array("frm_companyName", $fieldArray)) {
    echo " ---- Working ---- ";
}
```

to just echo out a message but it isn't echoing so there is definitely something wrong with the check i.e. the in_array.

Comment: What does `var_dump($fieldArray)` say?

Comment: @Jack I get: array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "frm_companyName" }

Comment: Your code [should work fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a2nlGW).

Comment: @Jack thanks for your help Jack by using the method to var_dump the array you suggested it got me thinking and looking at other parts of the code (over 1000 lines in total) I soon tracked down the problem. Again thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you missed the `!` sign like so:

```
// Check for missing field
if ( ! in_array("frm_companyName", $fieldArray)) {

    $errorArray[] = "Company Name";

}
```

Comment: Hi I assume the ! checks if the "frm_companyName" is NOT there, it is there, and I want it to check it IS there. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys,

I managed to track down the problem to some earlier code that was interfering. I couldn't post it all as there are over 1000 lines.

Thanks again though.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (in_array("frm_companyName", $fieldArray)) {
    $errorArray[] = "Company Name";
}
```

is the cause of issue. You should not put String into the array directly.
Instead you may want to specify the index of the array, for example

```
$errorArray[0] = "Company Name";
```

or just push the string into the array.

```
array_push($errorArray, "Company Name");
```